# Display Best Score Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsuserdefaults

I have already set up NSUserDefaults to get the score and display it. But now I'm trying to display the best score but the labels keep displaying the same integer

```
savedScoreMax = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"max_score_key"];
highScoreLabelMax = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %d",savedScoreMax] fontName:@"a2203.ttf" fontSize:21.0f];
highScoreLabelMax.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
highScoreLabelMax.color = [CCColor blackColor];
highScoreLabelMax.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.6f); // Top Right of screen
[self addChild:highScoreLabelMax];

savedScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score_key"];
highScoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",savedScore] fontName:@"a2203.ttf" fontSize:21.0f];
highScoreLabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
highScoreLabel.color = [CCColor blackColor];
highScoreLabel.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.4f); // Top Right of screen
[self addChild:highScoreLabel];

if(savedScoreMax>savedScore) savedScore = savedScoreMax;
```

Whats wrong here? The code works perfectly and runs fine but it diplays the same integer. Thank you :D

Update

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair monsterCollision:(CCNode *)monster projectileCollision:(CCNode *)projectile {

[monster removeFromParent];
[projectile removeFromParent];

score++;
[scorelabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score]];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"score_key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"max_score_key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

return YES;
}
```

New code with Integration of abhineetprasad's code

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair monsterCollision:(CCNode *)monster projectileCollision:(CCNode *)projectile {

[monster removeFromParent];
[projectile removeFromParent];

score++;
[scorelabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score]];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"score_key"];
maxScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"max_score_key"];

if(score > maxScore){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:maxScore forKey:@"max_score_key"];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

return YES;

}
```

Labels with the string

```
savedScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score_key"];
afterscorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",score] fontName:@"a2203.ttf" fontSize:23.0f];
afterscorelabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
afterscorelabel.color = [CCColor blackColor];
afterscorelabel.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.60f);
[self addChild:afterscorelabel];

bestScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"max_score_key"];
bestscorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %d",maxScore] fontName:@"a2203.ttf" fontSize:23.0f];
bestscorelabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
bestscorelabel.color = [CCColor blackColor];
bestscorelabel.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.50f);
[self addChild:bestscorelabel];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same key for savedScore and savedScoreMax. Use some other key for savedScoreMax , such as "max_score_key".

NSUserDefaults is basically a dictionary which can have several key-value pairs. The keys that you choose must be unique or you would end up overwriting the value of that key.

**EDIT**:

You are saving the value of `score` to both the keys and hence they are returning the same values. I believe you would want to save into max score only when your previous max score record is broken.
Use the following code,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"score_key"];
int maxScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"max_score_key"];

if(score > maxScore){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"max_score_key"];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: I tried it out and it still is displaying the same score :( any other suggestions?

Comment: can you post the code where you are saving the max score?

Comment: It's not working, the key "max_score_key" isn't updating @abhineetprasad

Comment: I added the code with integration of the code you gave me

Comment: max_score_key will only get updated when score is greater than the value already stored in max_score_key. Try deleting the app and then running it. That should erase the stored value of max_score_key.

Comment: i've edited my answer. was setting maxScore in place of score inside the if condition. sorry ..my bad!

Comment: Finally it works xD thank you very much for all the help